# How to display boxes over an image with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, image

I currently have an image that I want people's annotations to show up on, where the annotations actually have an x,y coordinate relative to the image, as well as a width and height. Let's say for now the annotations don't actually have text in them -- they'll just be empty boxes.

I'm wondering what the best way to display an empty box over the image would be, such that the user could click it. I know to raise the z-index of the annotation box, but I'm not sure where I would call the JQuery insert function, since the  tag can only contain an image. Should I wrap the image in a  and call Jquery insert annotation divs into the parent div of the image?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jasie, I'm curious: how do you let your users annotate the image? Can they just draw a rectangle on it? Or do they have to provide the coordinates. Could you show us some (javascript) code of that?

Comment: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/ :)

Comment: Sweet, a nice jQuery plugin, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this

XHTML

```
<div class="img-container">
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-container {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-container span {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

jQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // calculate the annotation text here
    $('.img-container').append('<span>' + annotationText  + '</span>')

});
```

That should get rolling... :)

Comment: Thanks alex, that worked perfectly. May I ask why img-container has a position:relative; tag?

Comment: Sure you can Jasie! It has position: relative so any child elements with position: absolute are calculated from the parent.